# Sharing database between different activities

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am writing a program that it needs Activity A to write data to a database, while Activity B read data from the database. I extended SQLiteOpenHelper Class as DatabaseHelper, and I get my database in Activity A in this way:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "classtableDatabase", null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

It works in Activity well.
When I try to open the database created by Activity A in Activity B in same way, it failed and I get these error messages:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cn.square2.iscut/cn.square2.iscut.ClassTableDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:231)
at cn.square2.iscut.ClassTableDetails.<init>(ClassTableDetails.java:28)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
... 11 more
```

What should I do to fix this issue? Thank you for your help!

Comment: make sure that you `this` refer to application context not activity context. and please post your code.

Comment: @minhaz : Why application context and not activity context? In most cases an activity context is fine although without further code, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Are you using the same code for opening database in `Activity` A and B? are you closing the database in `Activity` A when you are moving to `Activity` B..

Comment: please share the full logcat logs....

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar I updated this post with full LogCat logs. Thank you for your concentration!

Comment: @minhaz The code posted was all my code for opening database. But `this` is always refer to current class, isn't it? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: what is class `ClassTableDetails`. is it an activity? are you calling `getReadableDatabase()` from its constructor? In which method are you calling the database open methods?

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar class `ClassTableDetails` is an activity. I call `getReadableDatabase()` directly from a SQLiteOpenHelper object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. You don't need to do anything just make static references to the database from the activities other than your `MAIN` activity.